# Gaps between successive floating point numbers

Tags: numbers, computer-science, representation

(all numbers discussed are in decimal)

lets say we have a floating point data type that is like :

> m * 10 ^ e

```
where m is the mantissa . and max mantissa size is 1 ( 0 <= m <= 9);

e is the exponent and its size is  -1 <= e <= 1
```

we say our data type Max value is 90 and its Min value is 0

BUT : that does not mean we can represent all numbers that are in this limit .
we can only represent 27 numbers ( 9 * 3 ) excluding zero.

specifically we can't represent 89 in this way since it has a two digit mantissa 
(and non of them are zero).

so technically analogous to the above descriptions . in a float data type (in any programming language) there must be some integers between Max and Min values that we cannot store in a float data type .

is the above argument sound . if it is please give an example how to show this in java or c ?

Comment: When you say "in any programming language", you really mean that "all numbers are decimal" doesn't apply anymore and that you want to generalize to base 2, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is perfectly sound. The easiest to show it is be example, as you did.

### An non-representable example

Consider the "usual single floating point" format, as defined by [IEEE-754](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE-754), it has 7 exponent bits, thus a range beyond `[-2^127,2^127]`.

It also has 24 mantissa bits, so let's consider 
67108864, 67108865 and 67108866. Those numbers are respectively 2^26, 2^26+1 and 2^26+2.

Try to normalize them to write them in the floating point format, and you'll see that

- the mantissa gets value 26
- the first bit disappears, because it is implicit in the IEEE-754 format that the first number is always* 1, so you're left with 25 bits for each number
- all the next bits (in the limit of 24 bits) make up the mantissa...

  - 67108864 has only zeroes in its mantissa, since it's smallest bit is 0 you can remove it without losing information.
  - 67108866 has a 1 in its mantissa's last position, since it's smallest bit is also 0 you can still remove it without losing information.
  - 67108865 has only zeroes and a 1 as smallest bit, that is beyond the 24 bits ! So the number will be rounded to either 2^26 or 2^26+2.

Thus you have an example, like 89 :  67108865 is not representable in a float.

---

* except for subnormals, see below (expanding on the comment)

### Bias

Indeed I skipped a part here. The exponent is not directly encoded in the bits that are reserved to it, it is *biased*. In the case of single floating points, the bias is 127.

So our 26 is actually represented by 26+127, thus 153. Stealing the following image from wikipedia :

[image: negative zero drawing to illustrate floating point format]

If you take those numbers (sign, exponent and mantissa) as they are written and want to express a non-subnormal number, you get : (-1)<sup>sign</sup> * 2<sup>(exponent-127)</sup> * 1.mantissa

### Subnormals

Once we reach the smallest possible exponent, that is once we write it 0 and mean -127, we stop supposing the initial 1. This, way, we can represent numbers smaller than 2<sup>-127</sup> (by sacrificing precision, because we will have leading 0's on the mantissa).

We then have : (-1)<sup>sign</sup> * 2<sup>-127</sup> * 0.mantissa

In particular, when the mantissa is all 0's, we have 0, and this is intended : now a number that has only 0's in its binary representation is read as 0. In some way, 0 is the smallest of subnormal numbers (though in practice people consider it just a special case on its own).

Other special cases are when the exponent is all 1's. If the mantissa is all 0's then you have +/- infinity (depending on the sign), and if some mantissa bits are set you have a NaN.

Comment: there is something i do not understand . if the most significant digit of every binary number is assumed to be "1" then : 1.how do we express 0 in IEEE-754   2. if that's the case then we would be able to save 2^24+1 ( decimal : 16777217 / binary : 1000000000000000000000001  )  in float but we cannot ( when i tested it in java it got rounded to 16777216 )

Comment: @kiyarash I updated with that in the answer, though it's beyond the scope of the question. Most references are pretty fuzzy, I would recommend this introduction however : http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your reasoning is sound, and it should be easy to find real numbers that cannot be represented in your data type.

Consider the smallest mantissa (0) and exponent (-1) you allow:

```
0 * 10 ^ -1
```

= 0.0

The next-higher mantissa you allow is 1:

```
1 * 10 ^ -1
```

= 0.1

You cannot represent any real numbers between 0.0 and 0.1 exclusive, such as 0.05.

You should be able to express this in Java or C.